# How find the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}\left(1-\frac{x\ln{n}}{n}\right)^n$ convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question:**
Study the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^p}\left(1-\dfrac{x\ln{n}}{n}\right)^n$$

convergence,when $p$ and $x$ such what conditions?

**My try:**

since
$$\dfrac{1}{n^p}\left(1-\dfrac{x\ln{n}}{n}\right)^n=\dfrac{1}{n^p}e^{n\ln{\left(1-\dfrac{x\ln{n}}{n}\right)}}=\dfrac{1}{n^p}e^{n\left(-\dfrac{xln{n}}{n}+o(-\dfrac{xln{n}}{n})\right)}=\dfrac{1}{n^p}e^{-x\ln{n}+o(-x\ln{n})}$$
and my try is usefull? and How solve this problem, Thank you.

Comment: Big big hint: $e^{x\ln n}$ $= \left(e^{\ln n}\right)^x$ $= n^x$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can find easily that
$$\dfrac{1}{n^p}\left(1-\dfrac{x\ln{n}}{n}\right)^n\sim_\infty\dfrac{1}{n^p}\dfrac{1}{n^x}=\dfrac{1}{n^{p+x}}$$
so the necessary and sufficient condition of the convergence is
$$p+x>1$$

**Added** *Following the Sundaycat's request*

Recall that $\ln(1- x)\sim_0 -x$ so
$$\left(1-\dfrac{x\ln{n}}{n}\right)^n=\exp\left(n\ln\left(1-\dfrac{x\ln{n}}{n}\right)\right)\sim_\infty\exp(-x\ln n)=\frac{1}{n^x}$$

Comment: could you show the process that how you achieve $\frac{1}{n^x}$

Comment: It's the same process that the OP did and adding the Steven's comment.

Comment: Still don't get it, could you write down the critical step?

Comment: I added some details I hope useful

Comment: Thanks for the help:), I have a silly question, what does those symbol "∼∞" means here?

Comment: The symbol $u_n\sim_\infty v_n$ means that the sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$ are asymptotically equivalent at $\infty$ i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=1$ and we use this result: if $u_n\sim_\infty v_n$ then the series $\sum u_n$ and $\sum v_n$ are the same nature (both convergent or both divergent).

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Can I apply this result if $u_n,v_n$ are alternating sequences?

Comment: @sundaycat No this result is for positive sequences. For example the series $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}-(-1)^n}$ is divergent despite we have $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}-(-1)^n}\sim\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$